# mysql prepared statement unable to execute. Getting error 1064 in prepared statement

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures, prepared-statement, mysql-5.6

Query is retrieving correct result but in Prepared statement getting error "Error Code: 1064. check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO audittrail(BATCHID,IPADDRESS,DATE,LINENAME,ACTION) values (1165' at line 2"
Thanks in advance:-)

```
CREATE DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost'
PROCEDURE new_procedure()
BEGIN

DECLARE stmt text;

SET @stmt = (SELECT CONCAT('START TRANSACTION; \n', GROUP_CONCAT(objdata SEPARATOR ';\n'),';\nCOMMIT; \n DELETE FROM qry_obj_dtl where id in (',GROUP_CONCAT(ID SEPARATOR','),');') AS objData1 FROM qry_obj_dtl);

SELECT @stmt;

PREPARE param_stmt FROM @stmt;

EXECUTE param_stmt;

DEALLOCATE PREPARE param_stmt;
  
END
```

Comment: 'Executed below procedure ' - did you?- then you must have transcribed it incorrectly because what you have published does not syntax..Also publish sample data and expected outcome as text to clarify.

Comment: use temporary table and then drop it.

Comment: Getting error 1064 in prepared statement.
My result from query contains result as below.

START TRANSACTION; 
INSERT INTO audittrail(BATCHID,IPADDRESS,DATE,LINENAME,ACTION) values (11654565,"MAT-IT-1607 (00)","2000-00-00","xxxxxx","xxxxxx(MAT-IT-1607 (00)).
PRN file(pallet lable final eu.prn) changed.
Level : Pallet by xxxxxx
Remark: ok");
COMMIT; 
DELETE FROM qryobjdtl where id in (11654565);

Comment: @P.Salmon Data added.

Comment: You can only submit 1 statement at a time to dynamic sql..

Comment: @P.Salmon okay thanks, Is there a anyway i can work this out?